# Cross-posting Cstheory Blog Posts

Tags: discussion, policy, blog

If we write a blog post for the cstheory community blog, may we crosspost the same post to our own blog as well, with both posts pointing to each other?

I noticed this issue was discussed in the comments of [this post and its answers](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/community-blogging), but I don't think we came to an agreement.

EDIT: Unless I hear otherwise, I will assume cross-posting is okay.

Comment: is there a mechanism in place to make one blog post appear on two blogs? Or would you have to copy and paste the same text and inter-link?

Comment: I would do the latter: post it on two blogs and inter-link, like: http://hunch.net/?p=1569 and http://cacm.acm.org/blogs/blog-cacm/100785-to-videolecture-or-not/fulltext

Comment: cross listing is fine, as far as I am concerned. But really we need the blog editors to chime in

Comment: There is no rule.  I think it is for StackExchange to clarify, if they choose to.  I don't care, one way or the other.  Rebecca Chernoff, et al., seem to care, though, and would prefer it didn't happen -- "content farming" was a phrase used.  But there is no rule saying we can't do it, and I would *love* to post something written by Lev.  So unless Joe comes over the top and says no, let's go for it.

Comment: Thanks! (I've submitted a blog post for approval). I think what I might do instead is post a summary on my blog or something.  The reason I wanted to cross-post is because a blog post is a lot of work and is also informative to the readers, and the readerships of the two blogs probably don't overlap by much.  But I could just as easily do a summary or a pointer instead... I'll see.

Comment: I agree with Aaron. I didn't write an answer simply because I didn't think there was a hard and fast rule either way. And thanks for the post! I think as it is now Friday, we will probably leave it until early next week so that it gets most attention.

Comment: @Aaron maybe you should make this an answer (that there's no policy, you and Joe don't mind, but the SE ppl do), and I'll accept it?

Comment: I like the option Lev mentions of creating a pointer from your own blog to cstheory blog. This would be especially useful in these early stages when the cstheory blog has low readership. If high-visibility bloggers wrote a technical post for cstheory and then summarized and linked to it from their blog.

Comment: Yes, I've become convinced that's better than crossposting :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no rule. I think it is for StackExchange to clarify, if they choose to. I don't care, one way or the other. Rebecca Chernoff, et al., seem to care, though, and would prefer it didn't happen -- "content farming" was a phrase used. So as far as I'm concerned, if the content is high quality, and original to the CSTheory blog, it is fine with me if it is also "simultaneously original" somewhere else.

I would not want to repost something already posted somewhere else a year ago.  But material that appears the same day on the community blog and someone's personal blog seems fine to me.  I don't think it matters where it appears first.

One possible exception: the community blog is on the TOC Blog Aggregator.  If the writer's personal blog is, also, that would cause two copies of the same post to show up in everyone's feed, which seems a bit rude.  So I'd want to discuss it with Joe if we are ever in that situation.